# A proposition about bounded and weak-$L^2$ integrable fucntion

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, weak-lp-spaces

I have this proposition that I have no idea how to start. any hints helps.

> If $f\in L^{2,\infty}\cap L^{\infty}$ then $f\in L^p$ for $p\geq2$

and the second part asks me to generalize this result.

$L^{p,\infty}:=\left\{f:||f||_{p,\infty}:= \text{sup}_{\lambda>0}\lambda \mu(\{|f(x)|>\lambda\})^{1/p} <\infty\right\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer to your question. I haven't managed to solve the case $p=2$ yet.

By Fubini's theorem, we may write 
$$
\int_\Omega |f|^p\, d\mu = p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \mu(\{|f|> t\}) dt.
$$
Let $f\in L^{2,\infty}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and suppose that $p> 2$. By our assumption, we have 
$$
\sup_{t\ge 0} t^2 \mu(\{|f|> t\}) = N < \infty.
$$

Since $f$ is essentially bounded, the left hand side reduces to
$$\begin{align}
\int_\Omega |f|^p\, d\mu &= p \int_0^M t^{p-1} \mu(\{|f|> t\}) dt \\
&= p \int_0^M t^{p-3} t^2\mu(\{|f|> t\}) dt \\
&\le  pN \int_0^M t^{p-3}\, dt.
\end{align}$$

This integral converges iff $p-3>-1$, i.e. $p>2$.

---

It is easily seen that this method can be slightly modified into proving that
$$
 L^{p,\infty}(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)\subset L^q(\Omega) 
$$
whenever $q>p$. As before, the method doesn't work for $q=p$ since $t^{-1}$ is not integrable in any neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 5):

BigbearZzz has shown how to deal with the cases $p>2$. The reason that their technique breaks down in the case $p=2$ is that the result is false there. This answer is intended to supplement their answer by giving a counterexample in the case $p=2$.

Consider $(0, \infty)$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure and let $f(x) = x^{-1/2} {\bf 1}_{\{x \geq 1\}}$. Then $f$ is not in $L^2(0, \infty)$ (by comparison to the harmonic series). Clearly $f \in L^\infty(0,\infty)$ with $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$.

It remains to show that $\|f\|_{2,\infty} < \infty$. First note that since $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$, we only have to compute $\mu(|f| > t)$ for $t \in (0,1]$. This we can do explicitly. For $t \in (0,1]$ we have,

\begin{align*} 
\mu(|f| > t) &= \mu(\{ x^{-1/2} > t \} \cap \{ x \geq 1 \}) \\
&= \mu( [1, \frac{1}{t^2})) = \frac{1}{t^2} - 1
\end{align*}

So $t^2 \mu(|f| > t) = 1 - t^2 \leq 1$ for $t \in (0,1]$. In total, this gives us that $\|f\|_{2,\infty} \leq 1 < \infty$. This means that $f \in L^{2,\infty}(0,\infty) \cap L^\infty(0,\infty)$ but $f \not \in L^2(0,\infty)$ and so $f$ is the desired counterexample.

Comment: I've never done anything regarding the weak Lebesgue space before so I though my method is just not good enough to prove the case $p=2$. Thank you for confirming the it really is not possible.

Comment: By the way, may I ask what does a generic element of $L^{2,\infty}$ look like? Is is easy to see or is there any intuitive reason that your function $f(x)=x^{-1/2}\mathbf 1_{\{x\ge 1\}}$ is in $L^{2,\infty}$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'l give this one to @BigbearZzz

Comment: @HurjuiIonut Rightly so, BigbearZzz gave a nice answer. This is only intended as a small addition to cover the missing case there.

Comment: @BigbearZzz If I'm honest, I don't know too much about weak $L^p$-spaces either. I thought of this example since $x^{-n/p}$ is a generic example of a weak-$L^p$ function that is not in the usual $L^p$-space over $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think I originally read about this at Terry Tao's blog [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/) following some other stackexchange question (see example 12).

Comment: Thank you. I'm also more familiar with other spaces like Sobolev of BV. I've never found myself in a situation where I'd need a weak Lebesgue space (yet).